# Adding support to mqtt protocol in mosquitto broker

Tags: android, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I am figuring push technology for one of the application, as MQTT is lighweight and required less battery power than the other technology. I choose it and it works well with Android Device.

But, i also have one requirement that application also contains Web portal, and server also needs to send MQTT message to browser. In order to do that, it is necessary to configure Mosquitto for websocket.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You've not actually asked a question here

Comment: @hardillb: You are absolutely right.

Comment: Mosquitto 1.4 will be released on January 24, 2015, Ref: http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/iot.mosquitto/releases/1.4/plan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a guess at what your actually asking here...

Mosqutto will add websocket support in release 1.4. At this time (04/01/2015) 1.4 has not been released, but you can build it from source.

You can find instructions to help build the correct level here.

https://goochgooch.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/building-mosquitto-1-4/

Answer (score 1):

With the version 1.4. Eclipse Mosquitto added inbuilt support for Websocket.

Reference: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/iot.mosquitto/releases/1.4